# Ограничение ввода количества знаков в input после точки

Tags: javascript, input

Как на js (без pattern) ограничить количество вводимых цифр после точки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function func(e) {
  if (e.value.indexOf(".") != '-1') {
    e.value=e.value.substring(0, e.value.indexOf(".") + 4); // цифра 4, устанавливает количество цифр после запятой, 
                                                            //т.е. если 4, то максимум 3 цифры после запятой
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="func(this)" step="0.01"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Весьма изящно)